# How to make 'Auto Complete String Parameter' required mandatory in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops, jenkins-groovy

For Jenkins Pipeline, I've a 'Auto Complete String Parameter' where in user types in text and matching options are listed.

But as it is not required parameter, sometime user enter no value and proceed with build and hence it fails after build is started.

To avoid this, is there a way to mark 'Auto Complete String Parameter' as required parameter so if value for it is not provided, build will not be started.

Comment: Have you supplied a `default` for the parameter?

Comment: By `default`, you mean `Default Value` or something else. For `Default Value`, I haven't provided default value as the parameter will have on the fly value and fixed default value won't work if that machine is not available.